# How do I sort int without stl liberaries

Tags: c++

I have a problem where I need to sort buses arriving at a bus station on the basis of time of arrival without using STL (standard template library) in ascending order

Comment: I'd just manually write a sorting algorithm and use that; there's plenty of examples out there...

Comment: Requirements are unclear, attempted solution not shown. If your attempt failed, show the attempt and explain the nature of the failure. It would help to show what a solution would look like if you were allowed to use STL.

Comment: There's always good old-fashioned qsort():  https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort (well actually it's not that good, but it works :) )

Answer (score 2):

You may first want to read about sorting algorithms in general. A good staring point is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

There you see many of them.

The recommendation for newbies is to start with bubble sort.

Please see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/) for an example including source code.

Then, you need to store your bus data in a `struct`. Along with the timing information. All those struct shoulb be stored in an array, best a `std::vector`.

Then you need to write a compare function for times. The complexity of this depends, if you have one varaible that stores the complete time, like in a unix timestamp, or in a struct, for example `tm`. Then you need to compare hours, minutes and seconds and some boolean relation.

But first, you need to read a lot, then think even longer on how to implement, and then write the code.